PHPStan 2/bleeding edge: PHPDoc tag @var with type UserBundle is not subtype of type Drupal\user\UserInterface
I am trying to get ready for PHPStan 2 by turning on the bleeding edge features in phpstan.info:
includes:
        # https://phpstan.org/blog/what-is-bleeding-edge
        - phar://phpstan.phar/conf/bleedingEdge.neon

Then I ran phpstan and found several errors:
 ------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  92     PHPDoc tag @var with type Drupal\custom_user\Entity\Bundle\UserBundle is not subtype of type  
         Drupal\user\UserInterface.                

UserBundle is an entity bundle defined like this:
final class UserBundle extends User implements UserBundleInterface, KeyPerUserInterface {
How do I modify my custom entity bundle to resolve the PHPStan error?
I tried adding UserInterface to UserBundle implements but that didn't fix it.
EDIT
I noticed the same error gets triggered on code like this:
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface $current_user */
$current_user = \Drupal::service('current_user');
$account = User::load($current_user->id());

Error:
  43     PHPDoc tag @var with type Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface is not subtype of type                                 
         Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxy.                                                                                          

This can be "fixed" by changing the typehint to AccountProxy instead of AccountProxyInterface, but the hint should be the interface, right? Because AccountProxy could be swapped out.
Another way to "fix" it seems to get rid of the typehint, but without the typehint, I can't click around in PhpStorm.

Looks like a bug report.  Not sure to where though.
